# How do I can display a string value without using the standard libraries in C language?

Tags: c

How do I can display a string value without using the standard libraries in C language? please see the following code:

```
//without using the standard libraries that other created it
int main() {
string str = "Hello";
//How do I can display str value without using the standard libraries that other created it?
}
```

Comment: what type is `string`?

Comment: Without using the standard libraries, there is no support for IO.

Comment: So, you want to avoid `printf` only or any other function from stdio.h/stdlib.h ?

Comment: @RSahu in the case of a Linux based system, the kernel system calls will provide facilities for I/O (it's what the standard library uses for I/O as well). `write()` being the one the OP is after.

Comment: **Why** do you want to avoid the C standard library? Are libraries other than the one defined by the C standard (for example POSIX) acceptable? Knowing your reasons would make it much easier to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson probably academic curiosity would be my guess. Along those lines, here's a nice write-up on similar lines: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do it :

```
// Declare the prototype for the write() function,
// with unspecified parameters because why not.
extern long write();

int main(void) {
    char const *str = "Hello";

    // Retrieve the length
    unsigned long size = 0;
    while(str[size])
        ++size;

    // Write to stdout (fd 1)
    write(1, str, size);

    return 0;
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0e2b3ccf23a0111).

Of course, it's as non-portable as it gets, and will probably fail to link or trigger UB on the majority of systems other than the one I pulled the declaration from (it's a Linux system call, declared in `unistd.h` which I retrieved from Coliru). But then, that's why we have the standard library in the first place.

Comment: Should note `write()` (as used here) is a Linux kernel system call., the `1` represents `stdout` which is usually your console/terminal/screen. It can be more clear to use `fileno(stdout)` instead of the magic number, although most people know `1` is stdout. You may also get a compiler warning if you do not `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: @SnakeDoc Yep, I forgot to mention it was a Linux syscall. However both `fileno` and `stdout` are from the standard library, so I shan't use them. The reason I declared `write` myself is that `unistd.h` pulls in standard headers for e.g `size_t`. It will compile fine without, though.

Comment: fair enough, I had forgot `fileno` and `stdout` where from the standard library!

Comment: @SnakeDoc: `fileno` is not part of the C standard library; it's specified by POSIX.

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, it's specified by POSIX but POSIX is a spec, not an implementation. In Linux the function `int fileno(FILE *stream);` is defined in `stdio.h` (part of the C standard lib). See: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Descriptors-and-Streams.html

Comment: @SnakeDoc: True. It depends on what you mean by "C standard library". `fileno` is not defined by the library section of the C standard; it is, on POSIX-conforming systems, declared in `<stdio.h>`, which is part of the *implementation* of the C standard library. The relevance of this distinction to the OP's question depends on just what the OP means by "without using the standard libraries"; from what the OP has written so far, I have no clue.

Comment: @KeithThompson well, whatever he could have meant, I'm pretty safe :p

Comment: @SnakeDoc well I've got some upvotes, and a fun little challenge. All's good for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, you can't, at least not if you want your code to be at all portable.

Almost certainly there's *some* way to perform output in C code without using the standard library. But the way to do that will vary widely from one system to another. A solution that works on UNIX systems, for example, almost certainly won't work on Windows, and vice versa -- unless that solution uses the C standard library, which is customized for each system.

That's why the standard library exists. And on freestanding (embedded) implementations that don't support the standard library, you have to write system-specific code to do any I/O.

If you want to know how to do I/O *on a particular system* without using the standard library, I suggest posting a new question.

```
int main() {
string str = "Hello";
}
```

`int main()` is better written as `int main(void)`.

There is no type `string` in C. What you probably want here is either

```
const char *str = "Hello";
```

or

```
char str[] = "Hello";
```

A "string" in C is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". It's a data format, not a data type. (C++ has a type `std::string`, but you're asking about C, not C++ -- and in C++ `std::string` is itself defined by the C++ standard library.)

The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) is an excellent resource.