# is it possible to perform I/O operations in C++ without using any header files?

Tags: c++, io, low-level

I just wondered, all I/O in C++ is done through the standard library header files which means (for C++ std libs) input and output streams or (for C std libs) means standard input/output functions.

My question is, **Is it possible to not use these at all, and directly interface with the stdin and stdout of the OS?**

In C++, without using any headers, I mean.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942275/how-do-i-can-display-a-string-value-without-using-the-standard-libraries-in-c-la) (that one is for C).

Comment: Any reason why you'd want to avoid using the standard libraries for this?

Comment: no, I just wondered. I probably wouldn't take the trouble to do it myself, but I still want to know if it's possible.

Comment: Anything is possible. It would just be a lot of work. The standard input /output are modelled as file streams by the OS. So you just need to write to those streams by calling the appropriate functions in the OS. How you call an OS function is dependant on the platform. But with a lot of work with documentation and some assembly its possible.

Comment: yes, certainly possible, can make you own libraries, or can define the functions of those or existing ones in your source without including it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
unsigned char in(unsigned short port) {
unsigned char rv;
__asm__ __voltaile__ ("inb %1, %0" : "=a" (rv) : "dN" (port));
 return rv;
}
void out(unsigned short port, unsigned char data) {
 __asm__ __voltaile__ ("outb %1, %0" : : "dN" (port) : "a" (data));
}
```

It exists...

Comment: Or more usefully for user-space under an OS, write inline-asm wrappers for system calls with x86-64 `syscall`, ARM `svc` or whatever.  The OP did ask to interface with stdin/stdout, no x86 privileged hardware I/O instructions.  (They fault in user-space unless you make a system call first like Linux `ioperm`, or if your program runs under DOS where all programs run in essentially kernel mode.)

Answer (score 3):

I read your question as: Can I access I/O functions without #including header files.  I see other people interpreted it as "without including the standard library header files"

The simple answer is "no".  I/O is not built-into the compiler.  It is supplied by libraries.

A more complex answer is you could replicate the contents of the necessary header files directly in your .cpp files to define the standard library support (or to define the OS support methods.) .  This would be a foolish thing to do, but it's possible.

---

An historical digression in response to the comments:

When the `C` language first came out it was revolutionary for many reasons.  One of the most important choice by the language designers (which is now taken for granted in most modern languages) is that the compiler and the language it accepted should be as small as possible without losing functionality.  This made the `C` compiler tiny compared to the other compilers available at the time (FORTRAN, COBOL, etc.)

The compiler was focused on **compiling** (Not pretty printing the source, or ....)

The language was focused on making everything possible without making anything required.  If you were writing an embedded program that manipulated bits on a digital interface, you did not have to pay for the ability to format double precision numbers for display on a line printer -- either at compile time or at run time.

This decision on the part of the `C` language designers has been questioned many times over the years, but the decision has always stood up to the challenge. It was the right choice at the time and it's still the right choice -- it's an important factor in what makes `C` and its descendants the foundation on top of which most of the rest of our rich computing environment has been developed.

Comment: I don't think so... Because, how does the compiler understand what we mean by `std::cout << whatever;` if it had no I/O capabilities? I think there is probably a way to write code on our own which interfaces with the language's I/O in a similar way to the stuff in `<iostream>`.

Comment: " I/O is not built-into the language. It is supplied by libraries" - well, sort of. standard library is not a part of language, but its specification is part of C++ specification. Also note that standard C++ library is linked by default, so replicating library headers *should be* portable. It's still silly, though.

Comment: @WarpspeedSCP  "How does the compiler understand ...`std::cout <<`"   Answer, it doesn't unless you include the appropriate header files.

Comment: @el.pescado  Good point. I edited my answer to say "not built into the compiler."

Comment: Maybe there is a section in the code of the compiler which specifically handles the standard library code. If so, I guess it isn't possible in C++ at all to do that.

Answer (score 1):

sure, you can do this on a unix system

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    write(1, "Hello world\n", 12);
}
```

or similar on a windows system using the operating system calls there.

Comment: yeah, that's similar to the other question there. but we would still need to include a header.

Comment: Well you could probably write something like :-
extern void write(int, const char*, int);
Instead of the header

If you don't want to use a library you can probably call the operating system using inline assembly :P

Comment: yeah, that is probably the (only?) way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is what the Linux kernel, or, for that matter any other os kernel does. Writing code to do anything with a system is completely possible without even one `#include` line. For example, the `kprintf` function in the Linux kernel is an example of such a function, it has no stl dependencies, since the kernel is self contained.

Of course, this may not be possible in user space since the os restricts access to the parts of memory concerned with putting stuff on the screen.